# Where to get information about API changes between JavaFX 2 and 8?

Tags: java, javafx-2

Where can i find informations on API changes between JavaFX 2.x and JavaFX 8? When i try to let my project run on a JDK 8 preview, i see that some things are broken - even if some of that might have its reason in the immaturity of a preview version, i'd also like to know how the APIs and the CSS changes between the two versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once JDK8 released most probably there would be "JavaFX Compatibility Guide" posted, similar to [JDK one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html).

But anyway JavaFX 8 is expected to be backward compatible to JavaFX 2. If you met any issues, please, file them at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com

Answer (score 1):

- all important (news, roadmap, rellease candinates) is on [FX Experience](http://fxexperience.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from browsing jira and checking what features are targeted for Lombard (= JavaFX 8), and following FX Experience, you can also find some information about new features on [the wiki](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/OpenJFX), such as:

- 3D features
- Rich Text API
- TreeTableView